# PowerQuery conditional statements on replace

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to figure out why the bold/italicized are areas that aren't working? Specifically what I'm noticing what's not being captured is if there's multiple spaces...

In regards to PDU  CABLES, my condition is looking for it specifically to have that double space in between but won't act on it.

As for ANIXTER  DALLAS, I've setup if it simply contains "ANIXTER" to make the changes.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Uppercased Text", each [DocumentItems_Vendor], each if ***Text.Contains([DocumentItems_Vendor], "PDU  CABLES") or*** Text.Contains([DocumentItems_Vendor], "PDU CABLES") then "PDU CABLES" ***else if Text.Contains([DocumentItems_Vendor], "ANIXTER") then "ANIXTER"*** else [DocumentItems_Vendor], Replacer.ReplaceText,{"DocumentItems_Vendor"})

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please mark the answer as having solved your question by toggling the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine as provided in question

[image]

```
  =Table.ReplaceValue(#"Uppercased Text", each [DocumentItems_Vendor], each if Text.Contains([DocumentItems_Vendor], "PDU  CABLES") or Text.Contains([DocumentItems_Vendor], "PDU CABLES") then "PDU CABLES" else if Text.Contains([DocumentItems_Vendor], "ANIXTER") then "ANIXTER" else [DocumentItems_Vendor], Replacer.ReplaceText,{"DocumentItems_Vendor"})
```